# How can cluster membership for a new point be predicted using the spectral clustering model generated by Power Iteration clustering in Spark MLlib?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-analysis, apache-spark-mllib

I am using the Power Iteration Clustering function from Spark MLlib to cluster an undirected graph. This model is expensive to compute when the number of nodes and the size of the affinity matrix is very large. In such a case, it becomes a very expensive process to re-estimate the clusters for new data.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to predict cluster membership of a new point from the *PowerIterationClusteringModel* object generated by Spark MLlib?
2. How can intermediate results estimated by the model be accessed from the model object, such as the estimated eignevectors and eigenvalues & the projection of the data points in the space spanned by the eignevectors? Currently, only the cluster assignments are exposed through the [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.PowerIterationClusteringModel)
3. I came across a few incremental/ online learning approaches for spectral clustering from [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/assign-new-point-to-a-class-using-spectral-clustering) question. Is there any available implementation of such methods on Spark?

   - [Incremental spectral clustering by efficiently updating the eigen-system](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hning2/papers/incremental_spectral_clustering.pdf)
   - [Incremental kernel spectral clustering for online learning of non-stationary data](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231214004433)
   - [A Fast Incremental Spectral Clustering for Large Data Sets](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6118531/?anchor=references)

Comment: Don't abuse clustering for prediction. If you want to predict labels, always train a classifier, it will be much better.